# Como chamar método com o parâmetro array em java?

Tags: java

Estou iniciando em java, tive apenas uma aula. Então estou fazendo uma programa para somar os itens de uma array, e tem que usar metodo. Esse é meu código.

**Principal:**

```
package exercicio3e4;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Somar x; 
        x= new Somar();
        x.y={1,4,6,8,1};
        x.calcular();


    }

}
```

**Somar:**

```
package exercicio3e4;

public class Somar {

    int[] y;
    void calcular() {
        int i = y.length;
        int total=0;
        while (i >= 0) {
            i--;
            total = total + y[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Soma da array: " + total);
    }


}
```

Comment: Basta você utilizar `void calcular(int[] x) { ... }` e para chamar `new Somar().calcular( array )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao puxar o método na sua classe principal você tem que passar os parâmetros necessários para o método trabalhar, esse parâmetros também tem que ser informado no método.

Exemplo:

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Somar x; 
        x= new Somar();
        int [] y={1,4,6,8,1};
        //passando os dados de y para o método
        x.calcular(y);
    }
}
```

Classe Somar com o método recebendo os parâmetros

```
public class Somar {
    //método com parâmetros
    void calcular(int [] a) {
        int total=0;
        //b recebe os valores de []a recebidos no método
        for(int b : a) {
            total = total + b;
        }
        System.out.println("Soma da array: " + total);
    }
}
```